# How to get a handle on a EmberJS view when an other element is clicked

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/aShMQ/4/

I have an Ember.TextField declared inlined within a template,
inside the template is a button that has callback.
I would like to be able to set the TextField.enabled=true when clicked.
Since the template is a element in a collection, it is impossible
to use an absolute path

Clicking on the edit icon in the JsFiddle example should illustrate what I am after

http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/aShMQ/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the `disabled` of the Textfield to a property on your `itemView`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/gXLXW/:

```html
{{view Ember.TextField disabledBinding="isDisabled" valueBinding="content.v"}}
```

```js
App.Items = Ember.CollectionView.create({
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'itemView',
        isDisabled: true,
        __edit: function(evt) {
          this.toggleProperty('isDisabled');
          console.log(evt.get('content'))
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The pangratz above example is not working for ember 1.0 pre because content is passed to subview as "view". I made some modifications to it to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/musashimm/T9q6R/